# Forcing Push Message send to a specific Device ID in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilepush, salesforce-sdk-android

After registering a push device in the All Contact List, a random GUID is assigned to the contact created for the device. And when a `ContactKey` is assigned to that `Device ID`, it gets assigned to a new contact with a different `Contact ID` in the contact model.

What happens next is that the `Device ID` is erased from the first Contact (with the random GUID) and given to the new contact. So if you're already using the GUID contact in a journey to send Push messages, if a `ContactKey` registration is forced on his device, the user stops recieving push notifications from that said journey.

Is there any workarround to that issue by forcing push notification sends in journey builder to a specific device or a procedure to allow users to continue recieving the notifications ?

Comment: Is there a reason you would target the random GUID `contact key` as opposed to the device?

Comment: Take into account that new SDK allows you to delay registration until contact key is set, see:https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/sdk-implementation/device-contact-registration.html#delay-registration-until-contact-key-is-set. I would mark this flag in your case

Comment: Yeah, I see this as A) Unnecessarily doubling your incoming Contacts ($$$) and B) Unnecessarily complicating your device to contact relationships. I would instead look at your approach to registering and adding your device/contacts as both BillMote and SebOB stated above.

Comment: In our case, random GUID contacts are anonymous contacts (just regular app users), and the contactKey registration in the SDK is triggered when they log into the app with their account, and it's at that moment that we can retrieve their contactkey and assign the device to the known contact. So in our use case we need to target both types of contactKeys

Comment: I'm just not sure why you would `target` the randomly generated GUID.  If you're sending to anonymous contacts then you could simply create an audience list based off the value (or lack thereof) of a `tag` or `attribute` that you set when the consumer logs in.

Comment: Also, given that your Journey seems to be targeting everyone, you could simply target your application in general as opposed to a specific device id.  Either way, this is a solvable problem.

Comment: @BillMote, I see your point but the problem is that an app user doesn't need to log in. Therefor the contactkey will not be set-up for them and will stay on GUID until they decide to log in. the problem here is really about the transition of the Device ID from a contact to another and how to manage that change during a journey since the contact that enters the journey gets stripped from their device id if they decide to log in.

Comment: Don't key on Contact Key.  That's my point.  Use something that will transition with them.